# Ruby, Rails and aliasing - stack too deep problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

My problem is with calling old aliased method in Test environment. Probably only with Factory Girl

app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  include Authentication
  include Authentication::ByPassword
  ...

  attr_accessor :skip_password_validations

  alias old_password_required? password_required?
  # alias_method :old_password_required?, :password_required?
  def password_required?
    return false if !!skip_password_validations
    old_password_required?
  end

  # def password_required_with_skip_validations?
  #   return false if !!skip_password_validations
  #   password_required_without_skip_validations?
  # end
  # alias_method_chain :password_required?, :skip_validations  
end
```

vendor/plugins/../by_password.rb

```
module Authentication
  module ByPassword
    # Stuff directives into including module
    def self.included(recipient)
      recipient.class_eval do
        include ModelInstanceMethods
        attr_accessor :password
        validates_presence_of :password, :if => :password_required?
      end
    end # #included directives

    module ModelInstanceMethods 
      def password_required?
        crypted_password.blank? || !password.blank?
      end
    end # instance methods
  end
end
```

spec/models/user_spec.rb

```
describe User do
    it 'test' do
      @user = Factory(:user)
      @user.should be_valid
    end
 end
```

spec/factories/user_factories.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do |u|
    u.sequence(:email) { |n| "login#{n}@example.com" }
    u.password 'qwertz123'
    u.password_confirmation 'qwertz123'
  end
end
```

Result is

```
1) User test
     Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     SystemStackError:
       stack level too deep
     # /Users/schovi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:197
```

When i debug it with debugger gem, I found that method `old_password_required?` point to the new method `password_required?` in `user.rb` and not in `vendor/plugins/../by_password.rb`

Get same result with `alias, alias_method or alias_method_chain`

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My opinion is: Using `alias` in Ruby is often a pain in the ass. So how about moving your `password_required?` into it's own Module and the calling `super` inside it, to call `password_required?` from `Authentication::ByPassword::ModelInstanceMethods` like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  module PasswordRequired
    def password_required?
      return false if !!skip_password_validations
      super # Is going to call Authentication's password_required?
    end
  end

  include Authentication
  include Authentication::ByPassword
  include PasswordRequired

  ...

end
```

Comment: Great idea of workaround. I will use that probably. But i am still curious, why i am getting that error.